# Como chegar a um elemento de um dropdown através de texto parcial em selenium - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

Como posso selecionar um elemento de um dropdown através de parte do seu nome?
Quero selecionar uma opção baseada em valores retirados de uma base de dados, mas estes valores não têm o nome completo dos elementos do elemento do dropdown, há alguma forma de fazer o selenium procurar o elemento através do texto parcial?

```
    modelo = googleSheet.modelo.upper().strip()
    select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/form/fieldset[6]/div/ul/fieldset[3]/div/ul/fieldset[3]/div/ul/fieldset/div/ul/li/label'))))
    select.select_by_visible_text(modelo)
```

Na opção de dropdown eu quero selecionar "Terrano II 2.7 xpto ol", mas o valor da minha base de dados é apenas Terrano II 2.7

Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para filtros mais complexos que os disponibilizados nativamente, sugiro fazer manualmente, algo assim:

```
for option in select.options:
    if 'Terrano II 2.7' in option.text:
        select.select_by_visible_text(option.text)
        break
```